# Making list inside ul to be vertically centered

Tags: html, css

i can centered my UL in a div. But i am trying to make my list to be 
`vertical-align:middle`. But the word still doesn't move to the middle.

my css code

```
.topnav{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:grey;
    display:inline-block;
}
.topnav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    border:black solid 1px;
    height:50px;
}
.topnav ul li{
    border:black solid 1px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
}
```

my html code

```
<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">C</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### All new edits ya dig.

Full code below.

### [JS Fiddle Kiddle Middle Exampiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uU5TV/)

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    display: table;
}
.topnav {
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    display:table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.topnav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:black solid 1px;
    height:50px;
    display:table-row;
}
.topnav ul li {
    border:black solid 1px;
    width:180px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
    clear: none;
}
a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main change here is the addition of a wrapper div to allow centering of the inner div.

Comment: OP could also set the display to table-cell for the beginning div to make sure the color is fluid. I used your JsFiddle as an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3zS7D/1/  Your answer is spot on, I am just a consistency freak.

Comment: OoooooHHH.. Touche. I couldn't up vote this answer anymore if I tried.

Comment: this is great. But how do i push the list into the middle of the ul ? margin: 0 auto doesn't work.

Comment: My most recent version is perfectly centered no matter your browser size:  http://jsfiddle.net/3zS7D/2/

Comment: My topnav have to be 100% width and grey background. But the UL have a max-width of 1000px.i wanted to make the list to be centered no matter 3 or 4 cell to add.

Comment: Just add one cell on each side with transparent everything and `visibility: hidden;`.  At least until I wake up...time for some damn sleep.  Stupid Stackoverflow keeping me awake 48 hours.

Comment: @Deryck wold like to have your input on how to solve it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .wrapper {
            width: 45%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .topnav{
            width:100%;
            height:50px;
            background:grey;
        }
        .topnav ul{
            list-style-type:none;
            border:black solid 1px;
            height:50px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }
        .topnav ul li{
            border:black solid 1px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 180px;
            height:50px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This isn't the exact solution but this will do the trick.
Adjust the width in .wrapper and .topnav ul li to add more menu items and center them
If this dosen't work then you can use positioning to postion the ul.
Hope this will help.